# EF Core - Connection string cannot be null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am using `ASP.Net Core 2.1` with `EF Core 2.1`

While running any Migration from PMC, I am getting the below error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString

This is how my Context class looks like

```
public class MyAppContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyAppContext>
{
    private readonly string _dbConnection;

    public MyAppContextFactory()
    {

    }
    public MyAppContextFactory(string dbConnection)
        : this()
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;

    }

    public MyAppContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyAppContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_dbConnection, opts => opts.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15).TotalSeconds));
        return new MyAppContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }


}
```

My Connection string is present in API layer in appsettings.json & as good practice I should not add any reference to EF in API/UI layer.

How do I set the connection string as per environment in such layered architecture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EF actually starts your application to generate migration as of 2.0 I think. You need to add DesignTimeDbContextFactory to your project that will query the connection string for this use case, e.g. like this:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<StorageContext>
    {
        public StorageContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true)
                .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StorageContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            Console.WriteLine($"Running DesignTime DB context. ({connectionString})");

            return new StorageContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just as try I tried with your snippet, but getting the error 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'SetBasePath' and no accessible extension method 'SetBasePath' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This comes from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` or `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`, not sure which one exactly. Basically you can change my implementation for whatever is best for you, the idea is that you inject the connection into your DbContext for migrations generation. Where you read it from and how is up to you.