# NInject and Migration using EF Core in Console app

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am using NInject container for Dependency Injection and Entity Framework Core as ORM. The setup is as follows:

DB Context Class

```
    public TarantoContext()
        {

        }
public TarantoContext(DbContextOptions<TarantoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<FileData> FileData { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FileExport> FileExport { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FileStatus> FileStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FileType> FileType { get; set; }
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
    TarantoContext.ConnectionString = configurationManager.DatabaseConnection;
```

I am reading the configuration from json and passing it to the DataAccess layer (to the context class). I have a few tables in my database and taking database first approach I created the necessary data models and completed the dbcontext class code. I am able to fetch the data without any problems. Now I want to add-migration (I may have more changes to existing tables and may create new tables) and ran the following in package manager console:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

which resulted in the following error because the connectionstring property is null

[image]

I can fix this by hardcoding the connectionstring in the OnConfiguring method which I have tried without any problems:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            // The connection string needs to exist in the migration project for the purpose of migrations. Comment it in production.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                "Data Source=temp;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=temp;Password=temp;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
            //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

but I do not think this is the correct way of doing migrations. Moreover I am not sure how to handle the migrations in productions if I am unable to set the connectionstring in Program.cs or outside of the dbcontext class. What I am interested in is learning any design pattern which other developers are using to handle this situation. Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, you can load the connection string while setting up services in the ConfigureServices method. Use the following code:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDatabaseContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(
         Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
         b => b.MigrationsAssembly("....")));
```

Now, the `GetConnectionString` call will retrieve the connection string from you configuration file i.e. `appsettings.json`. To handle different connection strings for different environments, you can override the default app settings using a `appsettings.<Environment>.json` file like `appsettings.Production.json`.

More on this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Check out the relevant MSDN documentation pages for these things as they contain a lot of information.

Comment: except that it isn't a asp.net application. there is no startup/OWIN start up in console app that I am aware of.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can use the same pattern i.e. loading the connection string from a configuration file based on the current environment and then passing it once in `OnConfiguring`. The `Configuration` class I used before is not part of ASP.NET per se, so you could even use that, though it would require more code to make it work. This would be the correct way to set it up though.

Comment: I think thats exactly what I am doing. Please see the code and description.

Comment: In that case you have the correct design pattern. The only problem left would be the ConnectionString = null error right? Refer to this post on how to use the DesignTimeDbContextFactory class to fix that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745874/ef-core-connection-string-cannot-be-null

Comment: thank you. Though I do not agree that all the configuration references should be added to the Data layer in order to recreate an instance of ConfigurationBuilder. This will render the configs to live at a lower layer and unused (because circular references are not allowed) rather than being accessible to all the layers if, for example, I have a separate service layer providing services like Logging, Config etc. Can you tell where to implement DesignTimeDbContextFactory and how to avoid duplication in API layer and data Layer if it is implemented in data layer

Comment: You could have another layer called Common or something that contains shared code for all other layers. You can simply implement the DesignTimeDbContextFactory in the Data-layer. If you have split your layers across projects then always make sure to execute `dotnet ef` commands from the folder containing the Data-layer `.csproj`.

Comment: As I already said I have another common layer for config, logging etc so you are just repeating what I have already done and implementing DesignTimeDbContextFactory in the Data-layer doesn't make sense to me. The reason is given above. dotnet ef is just an alternative in console and I did run add-migration from powershell. As I said the problem is how to set connectionstring in api layer so that the migration work instead of hardcoding. if duplicating ConfigurationBuilder in api and data layer is the only solution then I need to do some more thinking. Anyways thank you for trying to help

Comment: since I posted the question the team has decided not to take the migration route so I wouldn't be spending more time in near future.I'll keep the question open if somebody has a similar problem and can make better sense than me of your answer and the link you provided.